# How to make enable disable the required filed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have created one form in that form i have 2 hidden fields which are displaying after checking a radio button . the code is

```
  <style>
  .selectContainer{
  display:none;
       }


 input[type=radio]:checked ~ .selectContainer {
      display:block;
    }

 </style>
```

/*html code*/

```
 <label for="name"> Any Accompanying Person ?:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes">Yes
   <div class="selectContainer">
  <label>Person Details</label>
         <p>

     <div style="padding-left:70px;"> 
  <input type="button" value="Add Person" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
<input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
  </div>
   </p>
   <table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"  >
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <p>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
     <td>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text"  size="20" name="name[]" required>
      </td>
    <td>
     <label>Age</label>
     <input type="text"  size="20" name="age[]" required>
      </td>

      </p>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
   <div class="clear"></div>
      </fieldset>

      </div>

    </div>



    <h3>Choose Your Payment Option</h3>
      <h1>

     <div style="padding-left:150px;">
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="visa">VISA/MASTER CARD:<br />
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="cheque"> CHEQUE/DEMAND DRAFT<br />
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="neft">NEFT<br /><br/>

    </div>
   <label></label>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br />


       </form>
```

Here is my form .if user will check the "Any Accompanying Person ?" radio button then only name and age field will displaying that i am controlling throw style .

problem: when user submit the form without checking the "Any Accompanying Person ?" radio button then all so name and age fields are showing required .but i need those field required when the user clicks "Any Accompanying Person ?" radio button .

how to do this?

Comment: how about creating the  'add person' form dynamically if the radio button is clicked? Also it should be a checkbox, as you've no way of unselecting a radio button (in your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#person').change(function () {

        $('#name').attr('required','required');
        $('#age').attr('required','required');

});
```

give the id person to  `<input id="person" type="radio" name="yes" value="yes">Yes`

give the id name and age to  `<input type="text"  size="20" name="name[]" id="name">`
give the id age to           `<input type="text"  size="20" name="age[]" required>`

Comment: need to give id to age allso ?

Comment: yes ... please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: didi you removed the required from name and age

Comment: yup . i just gave id .

Comment: no i mean did you remove the required attribute initially from the input fields

Comment: yup i have deleted . hey please check i have edited my code "Any Accompanying Person ?:" button is not inside the "<div class="selectContainer">" division

Comment: in the both case its not asking for required field . its moving to the next page directly

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#person').change(function () {

        $('#name').attr('required','required');
        $('#age').attr('required','required');

});
});

Answer (score 0):

According to your CSS

```
<style>
   .selectContainer{
     display:none;
                   }


    input[type=radio]:checked ~ .selectContainer {
      display:block;
    }

  </style>
```

The .selectContainer is not displayed and you are making it setting it displayed on selecting the radio button .In this case you cannot select the radio button as it is not visible due to your CSS.Set the visibilty for this selectContainer block so that you are able to select the radiobutton

and after that use ajax to check that whenever the button is checked that is

```
$('yourbutton').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(':on') {
        $('#name').attr('required');
        $('#age').attr('required');
    } 
});
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hey please check i have edited my code "Any Accompanying Person ?:" button is not inside the "<div class="selectContainer">" division

Comment: Now when you have not selected the radio button you should be able to submit the form without getting any error.

Comment: no its asking for fill the field . means name and age need to be fill even without clicking button

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
  .selectContainer{
  display:none;
       }


 input[type=radio]:checked ~ .selectContainer {
      display:block;
    }

 </style>

</head>
<body>
<form>

<label for="name"> Any Accompanying Person ?:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes">Yes
   <div class="selectContainer">
  <label>Person Details</label>
         <p>

     <div style="padding-left:70px;"> 
  <input type="button" value="Add Person" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
<input type="button" value="Remove Person" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /> 
  </div>
   </p>
   <table style="padding-left:50px;" id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"  >
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <p>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
     <td>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text"  size="20" name="name[]" required>
      </td>
    <td>
     <label>Age</label>
     <input type="text"  size="20" name="age[]" required>
      </td>

      </p>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
   <div class="clear"></div>
      </fieldset>

      </div>

    </div>



    <h3>Choose Your Payment Option</h3>
      <h1>

     <div style="padding-left:150px;">
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="visa">VISA/MASTER CARD:<br />
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="cheque"> CHEQUE/DEMAND DRAFT<br />
     <input type="radio" name="type" value="neft">NEFT<br /><br/>

    </div>
   <label></label>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code.this doesnot give any error. Then Add the ajax code or any scripting according to your requirement .